# Docker Nginx Hosts Cannot Be Resolved

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to connect to a proxypass in docker I have setup but I keep getting:

```
8#8: *1 api.example.local could not be resolved (3: Host not found)
```

I can access the proxy by going to http://api.example.com in my browser, but not if I go through the nginx proxy pass. My nginx is as follows, and please note that:

- Have ipv6 disabled
- I am resolving to 127.0.0.11

  ```
  server {
      listen   80;
      server_name  api.example.local;
      resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;

  location / {
      root    /code/api/public_html/;
      index  index.php index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?rt=$uri&$args;
  }


  location ~ \.php$ {
      root    /code/api/public_html/;
      fastcgi_pass php:9000;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
      fastcgi_param  ENV  development;
      fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
      fastcgi_read_timeout 9600;
  }
  ```

  }

  ```
  server {
      index index.php index.html;
      server_name www.example.local;
      resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
      error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
      access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
      root /code/main/public_html;

  location / {
      root    /code/main/public_html/;
      index  index.php index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?rt=$uri&$args;
  }

  location /api {
      resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
      proxy_pass_header  Set-Cookie;
      proxy_pass_header  P3P;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Fowarded-Host $host;



  set $upstream api.example.local;

      proxy_pass http://$upstream;
      proxy_connect_timeout 60;
      proxy_redirect     off;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
      root    /code/main/public_html/;
      fastcgi_pass php:9000;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
      fastcgi_param  ENV      development;
      fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
      fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
  }
  ```

  }

I also have the domains in my /etc/hosts. The OS is Ubuntu 18.04.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       my-comp

127.0.0.1       www.example.local
127.0.0.1       api.example.local
```

What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: Does `api.example.docker` resolves to something other than your host machine?

Comment: No it does not.  And I added my /etc/hosts above as well. @7_R3X

Comment: 127.0.0.11 is in host machine's network so the nginx container can't reach it. Docker creates it's own network ( for me it's 172.17.0.0/16 ), so no container will recognize a host beyond this range.

Answer (score 1):

The nginx container and the upstream server need to be on the same docker network.

Example:
Assuming the nginx container is exposed ports 443 on the bridge, create a docker network called nginx-network and join it to that network. 
Assuming also the upstream server is a container called ‘mysite’, join that container to the nginx-network, nginx will then be able to resolve the dns ‘mysite’.